# The Home fragment rises above the rest

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-bottomnav

when I switch between the fragment I created, the home fragment is not deleted, it writes on the others.

please i have an issue. I am using bottom navigation and nav controller. once I switch fragments, the home fragment keeps showing under the rest

```
`
class FeedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView


 //loadFragment(HomeFragment())
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation) as BottomNavigationView
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    loadFragment(HomeFragment())
                    true
                }
                R.id.nav_search -> {
                    loadFragment(SearchFragment())
                    true
                }

                R.id.nav_add -> {
                    loadFragment(AddFragment())
                    true
                }
                R.id.nav_notifications -> {
                    loadFragment(NotificationsFragment())
                    true
                }
                R.id.nav_profile -> {
                    loadFragment(ProfileFragment())
                    true
                }
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("Someone forgot to add enough fragment cases to 'when' clause!")
            }
        }


        }
    private  fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.cercevekapsayici,fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }`

`<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.FeedActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cercevekapsayici"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlRPg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D2Z8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llwZ5.png)`

I want the recyclerview to disappear when I switch to other fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your FramLayout height match parent :

```
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/cercevekapsayici"
       android:layout_above="@id/bottom_appbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadFragment` function replaces whatever `Fragment` is attached to `R.id.cercevekapsayici`, which is a `FrameLayout` that contains your fragments. But your `RecyclerView` is part of your main layout, so it will always be there whatever you attach to `R.id.cercevekapsayici`.

If you want it to be replaced, put it in a `Fragment` and add it to that `FrameLayout` - then it'll be removed when you switch to a different fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to give background to the other fragments